# The T-SQL error "invalid column name" cites my procedure name when running it

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am copying a stored procedure from one database to another. I am currently fetching the stored procedure with:

```
select OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.' + @stored_procedure_name, 'P'))
```

and store the returned string in the variable `@stored_procedure_defn`.

I then run the procedure with:

```
exec(@stored_procedure_defn)
```

However I am currently getting the error

> Invalid column name 'stored_procedure_name'

What could be causing this? I have tried it with a couple different procedures and the only time they mention their name is in the `create procedure [dbo].['stored_procedure_name']`.

**EDIT** Sorry my error is elsewhere. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why don't you try `PRINT @stored_procedure_defn` and show us the results of that, so we have some clue what you're dealing with? Also I strongly recommend using a 3rd-party tool for this kind of task. They've worked out all the bugs you've already come across, many that you will come across, and even some that you won't. See my post here about this: http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the stored procedure references a column that is not present in the "new" database. Note that the table is present, but the column (`stored_proceudre_name`) is not.

Based on what you've posted, the similarity of the invalid column name and your memvar name appears to be just a coincidence.

Comment: Yet I ctrl-F both procedures and 'store_procedure_name' isn't mentioned at all except at the beginning for 'create procedure [dbo].['store_procedure_name']'